# bind data when user controls can be switched in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I just worked with C# but do not have any idea on Silverlight so I am trying to know if there is a possibility of following.

I have 2 possible layouts for my list box items. so I have created 2 different user controls. Which are completely different that I cannot comprimise and put them in a single control and disable and enable on certain condition. I assumed that this approach will delay the load (correct me if I am wrong). So I am looking for a possibility if I can switch them from xaml. I can switch the control in c# code and even populate them. But data population in c# is a pain when compared to silverlight. I am asking this question only because I want to use data binding.

Is there a way to switch them from xaml. or is there a efficient way of doing this. Even a link of any article that can help is fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [DataTemplateSelector](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector) will be suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would disagree that data population in Silverlight is a pain.

On the contrary, this is actually one of the strongest benefits with Silverlight and Xaml, because of the excellent data binding capabilities you have access to.
So if you don't already, make sure you actually are utilizing this properly.

I don't know exactly how you would like to switch between these different views, but one way would certainly to bind the visibility of your views to another element on the page that determines which of them should be visible.
That way you can do it within Xaml.

Comment: I meant to say that data population through c# is pain compared to silverlight. That is why I asked this question.

Comment: Ok, makes more sense. But you still have full control over the data binding from the c# code behind the xaml.

Comment: After giving a thought I can assume that it is fine. So my requirement will be defining an ItemTemplate with conditions, can I that be possible.